# Fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 with only one partition: can I add a /home partition now?

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, home-directory, macbook

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 on my Macbook Pro (5,3 edition, 2009, SATA hard drive, 320 Gbytes). I used the automatic partition. Now I'd like to put my /HOME on a new partition so that, if I ever break my system, I can safely reinstall the system without losing all my personnel files.

I guess I must install GParted, but can I transfer /HOME while working within my session? Or should I use command lines in a terminal? Or should I start from the install CD? What's the safiest "modus operandi"?

[image: GParted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will help you create your /home folder after installing Ubuntu...

http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this points (at the moment) to an answer to the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This tutorial you give is quite interesting, but it is based on the fact that a new partition has been created fro GParted. But in my case, GParted sees the / partition and don't let me resize it to make room for a new one, because "this partition is in use". So I can't create a new partition from inside my system.

Comment: @greguti no one can modify the / partition when Ubuntu is running from that partition. It is like trying to change a tire while the car is moving. Use a live USB/DVD to shrink the / partition and create the place for /home partition.